# An example of commutative ring which has conditions regarding Jacobson radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

First of all, I use the following notations for ring $R$.
$J(R)$ is Jacobson radical of $R$.
$N(R)$ is nilradical of $R$.

Next, I say my question.

> I want to find a commutative ring $R$ which has following two properties.
>   $(1)$  $J(R) \neq N(R)$.
>   $(2)$  Krull dimension of $R/J(R)$ is not $0$.

Can you construct a commutative ring $R$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$ ?

Comment: Try, $K[x, y]\{z, w\}/w^2$, The power series in variables  $z, w$ ofer the polynomial ring in the variables $x, y$ modulo the ideal generated by the square of $w$

Answer (score 3):

Let $R = D[[x]]$ where $D$ is a Dedekind domain, for example $\mathbb{Z}$ or $F[x]$ for $F$ a field. $R$ is an integral domain, so its nilradical is trivial. Its Jacobson radical is $J(R) = (x)$, and $R/J(R) \cong D$ has Krull dimension $1$.